# HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create named query in net beans for restful web service project. Now I am trying to delete a table row  data with the reference of a field name "ordnumber",this is not a primary key,when  I am trying the url http://localhost:8080/TileApp/webresources/tile.ordermain/order/'52'

I am getting the error as

> HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed

Would you please help me for a solution.

```
   @DELETE
    @Path("order/{ordnumber}")
    public void deleteAction(String orderNO) {
        em.createNamedQuery("Ordermain.deleteByorderNo", Ordermain.class).setParameter("ordnumber", orderNO).executeUpdate();
    }
```

thank you

Comment: Its self explanatory, that url does not allow the `DELETE` http method

Comment: @joe Mather : then how can i test this url

Comment: you are mis understanding me, your tileApp is not configured to allow DELETE method of tht endpoint, you need to enable it

Comment: You need to set the HTTP request method to DELETE. Its probably going as a GET or POST.

Comment: thank you all for your suggestions,I got the result